# I am sometimes randomly logged out in the past 3 days

Tags: support, login, logout

*Yesterday* I was just browsing some questions from SOBotics, and decided to vote on one. But when I clicked the vote button...

> **You must be logged in to vote.**

When I refreshed the page - I was logged out. I logged back in. *Today*, when I tried to vote on another question, this happened again.

What is the reason for logging me out? Before these 3 days, everything was ok, and I didn't change anything on my side.

- **Update 1:** I was logged out yet again ~1 min ago, when clicked on review button in the navbar.
- **Update 2:** Logged out again.
- **Update 3:** Unexpected logout happened yet again.
- **Update 4:** You know what happened.

Comment: Very likely a cookies problem. Let's play a little game. You clear the cookies on your browser. Meanwhile, I've cleared your user account's sessions, which will force you to be logged out. Hopefully, when you log in again, it will stick.

Comment: @CodyGray you were too quick, when I clicked on my inbox, I was already logged out. Let's try again?

Comment: Well, that should have still worked. Clearing the sessions forced you to be logged out.

Comment: Have you tried to login with escalated privileges? Use "sudo login" to show you really mean it... a la https://xkcd.com/149/ :)

Comment: @JonClements I can create a tag sudo-login for this question, but I feel it would be burninated in 24 hrs. xD

Comment: **Is SO kidding me?** I was logged out yet again. Looks like your method didn't work @CodyGray :(

Comment: Sorry, not sure what else to try. I don't know much 'bout this here web stuff. You'll need someone smarter than me to help.

Comment: What browser are you using and do you have any extensions on your browser?

Comment: I'm thinking along the same lines as @George, your browser or some kind of an extension may be removing SO's session cookie.

Comment: @Shadow more specifically the `acct` cookie

Comment: @George Sorry for delayed response, I am using Chrome 60.0.3112.101 (latest at the moment) on Win7 x64. The only extension related to cookies is EditThisCookie, but I neither updated it recently nor had any problems with it before these 2 days. Also I am using [these extensions](https://imgur.com/a/PjvAM) (the gray mail is Checker Plus for Gmail), if that matters.

Comment: What are your current settings for saving cookies? Do you allow everything, do you have a whitelist of sites you allow to set them (and if so, what do they look like for Stack Exchange sites), or something else?

Comment: Also, what happens when you use a different browser?

Comment: @BSMP I allow cookies for all sites; didn't try another browser yet.

Comment: I have this problem too, but instead of every couple of days it's about two or three times a month, not big enough for it to be a problem but annoying none the less when it happens. I'm on a Macbook using Chrome 54 if that helps.